# Why is Selenium Grid behaving differently when starting it from within Java code than outside?

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium

I want to start and shutdown a selenium grid from within a spring boot application. **The grid is accessed periodically in parallel using several threads to get the response from several websites with java script support.**
When i start the grid **before** i start the application, everything is working fine, however when i start the grid from within the java code, **the first time the grid is used by some threads it is working as intended**, however after the thread pool is finished + terminated and the process is repeated **the program throws following error**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request timeout
Command duration or timeout: 30.05 seconds
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at net.JsSeleniumGrid.getHtml(JsSeleniumGrid.java:100)
    at net.CrawlCareerLinkRunner.run(CrawlCareerLinkRunner.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request timeout
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'olw', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.11.0-34-generic', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:118)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I seem to be able to still instantiate the `RemoteWebDriver` object since the logger prints:

```
2021-09-15 16:28:22.300  INFO 39465 --- [ null to remote] o.o.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake    : Detected dialect: W3C
```

The class i am using to start or shutdown the grid is following:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SeleniumGrid {

    public Process hub;
    public Process node;
    public String gridPath;
    private final ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
    private final ChromeOptions chromeOptions;

    public SeleniumGrid(ChromeOptions chromeOptions){
        gridPath = String.format(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources/grid/");
        log.info("Directory path of Selenium Grid set to {}",gridPath);
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().directory(new File(gridPath));
        this.chromeOptions = chromeOptions;
    }

    public boolean restartSeleniumGrid(){
        return (shutdownSeleniumGrid() && startSeleniumGrid());
    }

    public boolean startSeleniumGrid(){
        try {
            this.hub = executeCommand("./startHub.sh");
            this.node = executeCommand("./startNode.sh");
            log.info("Selenium grid started successfully.");
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }

    public boolean shutdownSeleniumGrid(){
        if(this.node != null){
            this.node.children().forEach((child) -> child.destroy());
            this.node.destroy();
        }
        if(this.hub != null){
            this.hub.children().forEach((child) -> child.destroy());
            this.hub.destroy();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private Process executeCommand(String cmd) throws IOException {
        processBuilder.command(cmd);
        return processBuilder.start();
    }
}
```

Whereas ./startHub.sh and ./startNode.sh are just wrapper scripts for the longer commands needed to start the grid.

startHub.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Starting Selenium Grid in HUB mode'
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json
```

startNode.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Starting Selenium Grid in NODE mode'
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

When i debug i can connect to the Grid interface completely normal with `http://localhost:4444/`, everything behaves fine up until that second attempt. The problem clearly does not occur because of some configuration within the `WebDriver` or the Grid / Node since it is working perfectly fine when i manually start it before the program execution in 2 separate shell sessions (1 Hub + 1 Node). Any ideas what could be the possible problem ?

Comment: It seems that if i limit the thread pool to only 1 thread... the error does not occur. My guess is that if the application starts the two processes... resource demand rises big time, causing the grid to work extremely slow... eventually causing above error. Is there a way to somehow detach the processes from the application ? I want it to run just as if it was run out of a shell session.

Comment: Try to start the selenium node with defined timeout values - please refer here : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters

Comment: @JayanthBala Like i stated above.. its not a configuration issue. ( I have set the timeouts in my *.json configuration files) It seems that the process is behaving differently because it is a child process of the application and not from the shell.(This is my assumption). Since this is a pretty clumsy solution anyway, i am now taking a different approach. I use a docker container for the grid, and start/stop it via a docker-api. Still want to know whats the issue here.